# Configure Workbox to use cached response when network response is a 404

Tags: service-worker, workbox

*This question was originally [asked in a tweet](https://twitter.com/adpeyre/status/1005002330272649216).*

Is there a way to configure [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) to respond with a cached response when a network response has an HTTP status of 404?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create your own custom [`handlerCallback`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.routing.Route#~handlerCallback) that accomplishes that. Some of the details will vary based on your specific setup (the cache names, the fallback URLs, etc.), as well as whether you want to use a formal Workbox strategy (like `networkFirst` instead of `fetch()`), but in general, the following should work:

```
// Assume that this URL is already cached somewhere, e.g. precached.
const fallbackUrl = '/404-fallback.html';

const notFoundFallbackHandler = async ({event}) => {
  const fetchResponse = await fetch(event.request);
  if (fetchResponse.status === 404) {
    return caches.match(fallbackUrl);
  } else {
    return fetchResponse;
  }
};

// To apply this handler based on a URL pattern:
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/some/criteria/to/match'),
  notFoundFallbackHandler
);

// Or, to apply this handler for all navigation requests, use this:
// const navigationRoute = new workbox.routing.NavigationRoute(notFoundFallbackHandler);
// workbox.routing.registerRoute(navigationRoute);
```